# Chain assertions together in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing

I have an operation that I want to succeed with two different conditions. For example, if the status code is 501 OR message is not 'FAILED'. Is there a way to have assertions grouped together logically like AND/OR. If assertion 1 passes OR assertion 2 passes, I want my test case to succeed.

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: Just as a general approach, why not check each condition and store it as a well-named var? Then you can assert `statusCodeIs501 || messageIsNotFailed` or whatever. That way your assertion line is clear about what it's checking. You could use `any` with a list of conditions if you want to check if one is true, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cactustictacs suggests "naming" your assertions and then chaining them.

I'll suggest an answer by showing code that validates 4x REST interface inputs that have some complex permutations that allowed / not allowed.  This code is arguably easier to read than a classic `if ... else` structure.

See how they are evaluated using the `when` construct.   Perhaps you can take these ideas for your assertions...

```
val userIdNotNull = userId != null
        && channelType == null
        && primaryMentorId == null
        && primaryClinicianId == null

val userIdAndChannelTypeNotNull = userId != null
        && channelType != null
        && primaryMentorId == null
        && primaryClinicianId == null

val primaryMentorIdNotNull = userId == null
        && channelType == null
        && primaryMentorId != null
        && primaryClinicianId == null

val primaryClinicianIdNotNull = userId == null
        && channelType == null
        && primaryMentorId == null
        && primaryClinicianId != null

val channels = when {
    userIdNotNull -> getChannelsByUserId(userId)
    userIdAndChannelTypeNotNull -> channelRepository.findByMemberIdAndChannelType(userId!!, channelType!!)
        .ifEmpty { throw NotFoundException() }

    primaryMentorIdNotNull -> channelRepository.findByPrimaryMentorId(primaryMentorId)
        .ifEmpty { throw NotFoundException() }

    primaryClinicianIdNotNull -> channelRepository.findByPrimaryClinicianId(primaryClinicianId)
        .ifEmpty { throw NotFoundException() }

    else -> throw InvalidRequestParameterException("This combination of request parameters is not supported")
}
```